# Creating a nested dictionary from file that has only text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file that has the headers and the value lines are:

```
site,access_key,secret_access_key
sa1,something,something 
na1,something,something
```

and so on. I would like the dictionary to look like

```
site_dict = {"sa1" :{"access_key" : "something", "secret_access_key" : "something"}, "na1" :{"access_key" : "something", "secret_access_key" : "something"}}
```

I tried what was suggested here : [How to create a nested dictionary from a csv file with N rows in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551040/how-to-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-a-csv-file-with-n-rows-in-python) but it deals with numeric values and I could not get my head around changing it to string values. Any help would be appreciated. If you make a suggestion or provide an answer please make it an answer so I can mark it appropriately. EDIT: I changed the sa1 and na1 to keys by adding the quotes.

Comment: Please show actual input, code, and explain what didn't work.

Comment: `import pandas as pd; pd.read_csv('data.csv').set_index('site').T.to_dict()` should do you the trick

Comment: http://www.shanegibney.com/shanegibney/convert-csv-to-json-with-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module for reading and preread the first line to get the key-names:

```
# create data
with open("f.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""site,access_key,secret_access_key
sa1,something111,something111 
na1,something222,something222""")

import csv

result = {}
with open("f.txt") as f:
    # get the keynames from the 1st line
    fields = next(f).strip().split(",")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # process all other lines
    for line in reader:
        # outer key is 1st value
        # inner key/values are from the header line and rest of line data
        result[line[0]] = dict(zip(fields[1:],line[1:]))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'sa1': {'access_key': 'something111', 'secret_access_key': 'something111'}, 
 'na1': {'access_key': 'something222', 'secret_access_key': 'something222'}}
```

Lookup: [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv)

Comment: Thank you so very much! This is far more elegant than what was suggested in the post I linked to.